# moving uploaded file to a dynamic table in php

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to move the file that I uploaded using move_uploaded_file. Here are my variables:

```
    $filename = $_FILES['File_file']['name'];
    $folder_id = $_POST['File']['folder_id'];
    $folder_name_result = $this->filemanager_model->getfoldername($folder_id);
    $fileloc = $_FILES['File_file']['tmp_name'];
    $folder_name = "";
    foreach ($folder_name_result->result_array() as $row)
    {$folder_name = $row['title'];}
    $pathAndName = "filemanager/".$folder_name."/".$filename;
```

And the outputs of the variables:

$folder_name = `Grrr`

$pathAndName = `filemanager/Grrr/cis.png`

$fileloc = `C:\xampp1.8\tmp\phpE21E.tmp`

When I run the move_uploaded_file function, it generates an error where:

`move_uploaded_file(filemanager/Grrr/cis.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

`move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp1.8\tmp\php2565.tmp' to 'filemanager/Grrr/cis.png'`

My filepaths:

`/admin` - base_url

`/admin/filemanager/Grr` - The folder I want it to save

`/admin/application/controllers/`- the path of my controllers

Is there something wrong with my code as to why it's not working?

Comment: Are you only passing a single argument to `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm passing 2 variables, `move_uploaded_file($fileloc, $pathAndName);`

Comment: Then check permissions on your destination path

Comment: Please include errors

Answer (score 0):

I just had something wrong with the formatting of my file path. I had to include the exact path since I'm on localhost, so once I put this on the server I've got to change path to the one on my server.

```
$pathAndName = "C:\\xampp1.8/htdocs/cicubecms/admin/filemanager/".$cat_name."/".$folder_name."/".$filename;
```